# How to disable hover property in fusion charts of water fall chart

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts, data-representation

I am trying to use water fall chart of fusioncharts API.
I want to disable hovering property of chart. Here you can see the on hovering it shows "Variable Costs, $-156K" on the "Variable Costs" column.

[image]

I am using some following configuration-

```
      {
"chart": {
    "caption": "Total Profit Calculation",
    "subcaption": "Last month",
    "yAxisname": "Amount (In USD)",
    "numberprefix": "$",
    "connectordashed": "1",
    "sumlabel": "Total {br} Profit",
    "positiveColor": "#6baa01",
    "negativeColor": "#e44a00",
    "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500",
    "baseFontColor": "#333333",
    "baseFont": "Helvetica Neue,Arial",
    "captionFontSize": "14",
    "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
    "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
    "showBorder": "0",
    "bgColor": "#ffffff",
    "showShadow": "0",
    "canvasBgColor": "#ffffff",
    "canvasBorderAlpha": "0",
    "divlineAlpha": "100",
    "divlineColor": "#999999",
    "divlineThickness": "1",
    "divLineDashed": "1",
    "divLineDashLen": "1",
    "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
    "showplotborder": "0",
    "showXAxisLine": "1",
    "xAxisLineThickness": "1",
    "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
    "showAlternateHGridColor": "0"
},
"data": [
    {
        "label": "Online sales",
        "value": "420000"
    },
    {
        "label": "Store Sales",
        "value": "710000"
    },
    {
        "label": "Total Sales",
        "issum": "1"
    },
    {
        "label": "Fixed Costs",
        "value": "-250000"
    },
    {
        "label": "Variable Costs",
        "value": "-156000"
    },
    {
        "label": "COGS",
        "value": "-310000"
    },
    {
        "label": "Promotion Costs",
        "value": "-86000"
    },
    {
        "label": "Total Costs",
        "issum": "1",
        "cumulative": "0"
    }
]
  }
```

You can also check the data and configuration at the following link.
[Waterfall Chart](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/waterfall-or-cascade-chart/creating-a-waterfall-or-cascade-chart.html)

Please suggest fusioncharts API way(If possible) to disable on-hover property. Other way solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disable the hover event by adding css rule to the elements.

**Jquery Solution**

```
$('div#chart-container-1 rect').css('pointer-events','none');
```

**CSS solution**

```
div#chart-container-1 rect {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

Note: `chart-container-1` was the id of the parent div which wraps the chart in the link you provied, you can change it to match your div.

`!important` is used in the css because the elements have inline styles for `pointer-events` and it takes priority in the rule, So override the inline property priority I have used `!important`

Also note `pointer-events:none` will remove all the mouse events including click, hover, mousein, mouseout etc..

Comment: Hi , Actually my platform limitation force me to look for some fusion charts API way of doing it. Although I also tried your solution for plan B. Situation is something like I have 3 such charts on page and when I attempted your solution. It just does disables hover of other two charts also.

Comment: You can control the behaviour by having proper selectors. Meaning use the id and specific elements in your selectors so that you target only requires section

Comment: After some more research I found "toolText" in chart attribute and I can surely change the value to nothing. This value is appeared when we hover on property. @Reddy - your solution is quiet clear and may be that is what fusioncharts api does internally. Hence accepting.

Comment: @reasonable_syam Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to disable the hovering property of chart by using "showHoverEffect" : "0" which will disable hover effect on all chart elements or you can use "plotHoverEffect" : "0" which will disable hover effect on charts for data plots only.

```
 chart  : {
"showHoverEffect" : "0",
"plotHoverEffect" : "0"
}
```

Hope this helps.